# How to filter IQueryable<T> with Expression on MethodInfo.GetParameters() via extension method? (almost solved)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

How do I filter an Entity Framework (EF) stored procedure by its input parameters? (The EF procedures are loaded via ILGenerator.)

The following code produces two errors:

1. > 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
   >   'Where' and the best extension method overload
   >   'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable,
   >   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has
   >   some invalid
   >   arguments
2. > Argument 2: cannot convert from
   >   'System.Linq.IQueryable>>'
   >   to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

> ```
> public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> methods, string filter) where T : MethodInfo
> {
>     IQueryable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> lambdaExp = (
>         from method in methods
>         where method.Name.StartsWith("PROC_")
>         from param in method.GetParameters()
>         let paramExp = Expression.Parameter(param.ParameterType, param.Name)
>         let constExp = Expression.Constant(filter, typeof (string)) // e.g. filter might equal "recid"
>         where param.ParameterType == typeof (string)
>         // This is to ensure that we only compare parameters of the same type.
>         let body = Expression.Equal(paramExp, constExp)
>         let lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, paramExp)
>         select lambda
>         //group lambda by param.Member  
>         );
>     // I want to be able to filter according to whether or not the expression evaluates to true.
>     methods = methods.Where(lambdaExp); // This is where I am stuck.
>     return methods;
> }
> ```
>
> Here is an example NUnit test method that might be used to test the above query:

```
[Test]
public void Filter_IsMethodFilteringProperly_ReturnsTrue(){
    var testnew = new CRMEntities();
    var myType = typeof(CRMEntities);
    var myMethods = myType.GetMethods();
    var newlist = myMethods.AsQueryable().Filter("recid");
    foreach (var methodInfo in newlist)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(methodInfo.Name);
    }
    Assert.AreNotEqual(newlist.Count(), myMethods.Count());
}
```

Comment: You need to pass an expression to `Where`, you can't pass what **you** have. Seems you are a bit confused by expressions. What you are trying to do, wont work.

Comment: @leppie, thanks for the comment. You're saying that I need to build the expression in a way that includes the call to the Where method, rather than trying to build an expression tree from inside a LINQ query?

Comment: Yes, so build `MyWhereClause` as `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` and you can pass that to any `IQueryable<T>`